# Is it valid to aggregate multiple participant recruitment sources?

Tags: methodology, experiment-design

For example, let's say you use Amazon Mechanical Turk for participant recruitment. What if you now also use online message boards? Can you aggregate the data together as long as the procedure for both sets of participants is identical? Could a reviewer reject your work because of this?

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with academia.

Comment: It's about recruiting participants for a study?

Comment: Are you asking or telling?

Comment: See this: https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, questions about the content of research are off topic. Sorry.

Comment: But this is somewhat about "processes of researching"?

Comment: @Josiah This question could maybe be better addressed on Cross Validated StackExchange.

Comment: Statistically it depends on how you handle it. If you just averaged them together and that's it, as a reviewer I'd suggest you have to do more than that or reject the paper. You may wish to familiarize yourself with the omitted-variable bias, for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias In short: if the participant recruitment matters (and it probably does) omitting this as a variable and simply averaging them together or including them in a regression but leaving this out as a variable is not appropriate and your results are much more likely to be wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your question is about the statistical validity of the results of a study using multiple recruitment sources for participants, then there is nothing inherently wrong with aggregating your data per se.

Be aware of course that "recruitment pathway" could be a confounding factor, depending on your study. This is going to be study specific. If your study is testing a new diabetes medication, recruitment pathway is not as important. If your study is looking at introversion and personality types, different recruitment pathways may yield significantly different results.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Comment: You should know better than to answer questions you voted to close.

Comment: @AzorAhai sorry. It will never happen again, sir. But you down vote half of my answers anyway, so I might as well get the +15 for an accepted answer, right? And it helped the OP, so mission accomplished!

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that I downvote you so much but ok